# Superseding java.util.Currency data with custom properties file on Android

Tags: android, currency

The Java SE [documentation of `java.util.Currency`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) says

> Users can supersede the Java runtime currency data by creating a properties file named /lib/currency.properties.

Can this be done on the Android Runtime? Can I for instance bundle a `currency.properties` with my .apk? (The [Android documentation of `java.util.Currency`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Currency.html#getInstance%28java.util.Locale%29) does not mention anything like this.)

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't conclusive, I don't see any evidence in this Java code that this is possible:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/luni/src/main/java/java/util/Currency.java#38
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/luni/src/main/java/libcore/icu/ICU.java#395